# Get dict key by max value

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I'm trying to get the dict key whose value is the maximum of all the dict's values.

I found two ways, both not elegant enough.

```
d= {'a':2,'b':5,'c':3}
# 1st way
print [k for k in d.keys() if d[k] == max(d.values())][0]
# 2nd way
print Counter(d).most_common(1)[0][0]
```

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Use the `key` parameter to `max()`:

```
max(d, key=d.get)
```

Demo:

```
>>> d= {'a':2,'b':5,'c':3}
>>> max(d, key=d.get)
'b'
```

The `key` parameter takes a function, and for each entry in the iterable, it'll find the one for which the `key` function returns the highest value.

Comment: What if there are multiple keys? Can I pass, say, `len` to get the longest key with the most value?

Comment: @SiddharthaRT: you can use a `lambda` for the key: `max(d, key=lamda k: (d[k], len(k)))` will return the key with the highest value, and if there is more than one such key, it'll be the longest key of those that is returned.

Comment: How would you do if you wanted not just the key with the max value, but if you wanted the first n keys with the first n max values in the dict?

Comment: @Tropilio then use [`heapq.nlargest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest).